Error when installing bundle which requires gem called rake
I have zero experience bundle, gem or ruby but need to update content in a website which runs through jekyll. I am using ubuntu machine and getting jekyll running has been a pain.
When I type bundle exec jekyll serve I get the following error : Run bundle install to install missing gems.
Then when I run bundle install. Any Suggestions ?
I get the following error
An error occurred while installing rake (13.2.1), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  jekyll-archives was resolved to 2.2.1, which depends on
    jekyll was resolved to 4.3.3, which depends on
      jekyll-sass-converter was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
        sass-embedded was resolved to 1.69.5, which depends on
          rake


If it helps this are the versions I have for each
(base) ➜  mlgh-sg.github.io git:(master) ruby --version
ruby 3.0.2p107 (2021-07-07 revision 0db68f0233) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
(base) ➜  mlgh-sg.github.io git:(master) bundle --version
Bundler version 2.5.7
(base) ➜  mlgh-sg.github.io git:(master) gem --version
3.3.5



rake is the Make-like program that's one of the standard gems in Ruby. As such it comes pre-bundled when you install Ruby.

Is there a reason you are using this old version of Ruby? Updating it might resolve the problem.

Is that all the error you got? No more specifics? Do not leave out text from your question that might be relevant if there was more output from Bundler. Also try with the --verbose flag and see if it would print the actual error. Also post the Gemfile so people can try to replicate the problem.
